# How to calculate % of data that falls in range out of σ?

Tags: standard-deviation

This is probably a rather basic question.
I quote from https://www.minitab.com/uploadedFiles/Documents/sample-materials/FuelInjectorNozzles-EN.pdf:

```
Typically, process variation is defined as 6s, where s is the
standard deviation, as an estimate of σ. When data are
normally distributed, approximately 99.73% of the data fall
within 6 standard deviations (± 3 standard deviations from
the mean), and approximately 99% of the data fall within 5.15
standard deviations (± 2.575 standard deviations from the
mean).
```

So for σ=5.15, we have 99% of the data fall in range, and with σ=6, we have 99.73% of the data fall in range. I've seen  Chebyshev rule: $1-\frac{1}{k^2}$, but it doesn't seem to be true for the values they give. Do they have a mistake, or I have a complete lack of understanding of this stuff? If their calculation is correct, how do I calculate % for any given σ?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=68+95+99.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Chebyshev's Theorem:** Chebyshev's inequality is a *theorem* that applies to any distribution
that has a (finite) standard deviation $\sigma:$ 
$$P(|X - \mu| \ge k\sigma) \le \frac{1}{k^2}$$
or
$$P(|X - \mu| < k\sigma) > 1 - \frac{1}{k^2}.$$

For example, if $E(X) = \mu = 1$ and $SD(X)= \sigma = 1,$ then Chebyshev's inequality
says that $P(|X - \mu| < 3) = P(-2 < X < 4) > 1 - 1/4 = 0.75.$

In particular, if $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=1, \sigma=1),$ then
$P(-2 < X < 4) = 0.9973 = 99.73\%,$ which is greater than 75% as promised
by Chebyshev's Inequality. [Computation using R below.]

```
diff(pnorm(c(-2,4), 1, 1))
[1] 0.9973002
```

Also, if $Y \sim \mathsf{Exp}(\text{rate} = 1),$ then $E(Y) = SD(Y) = 1,$
and $P(Y > 0) = 1,$ so that 
$$P(-2 < Y < 4) = P(0 < Y < 4) = 1 - e^{-4} =  0.9817,$$
which is also greater than 75%.

```
1 - exp(-4)
[1] 0.9816844
diff(pexp(c(-2, 4), 1))
[1] 0.9816844
```

Finally, if $U \sim \mathsf{Unif}(1-\sqrt{3},1+\sqrt{3}),$ then
$E(U) = SD(U) = 1$ and $P(1-\sqrt{3} < U < 1+\sqrt{3}) = 1,$ so that
$$P(-2 < U < 4) = P(-0.732 < U < 2.732) = 1,$$
which also exceeds 75%.

```
diff(punif(c(-2,4), 1-sqrt(3), 1+sqrt(3)))
[1] 1
```

Therefore, the Chebyshev bound may sometimes be useful and sometimes not
useful for practical purposes, but it remains true for *any* distribution that
has standard deviation $\sigma.$ Mainly, Chebyshev's Inquality is more useful
in mathematical proofs of other theorems than in practical applications.

**The Empirical Rule--'Exact' for Normal Populations:** By contrast, the Empirical Rule, is not a theorem, but a rough rule-of-thumb
that applies to many distributions and samples that are roughly normal.
It states that about 68% of the probability or observations lie within
the interval $\mu \pm \sigma$, about 95% lie within $\mu \pm 2\sigma$,
and about 99.7 (or "all or almost all") lie within $\mu \pm 3\sigma.$

The following computations in R show that the Empirical Rule is exactly true
(except for convenient rounding in the statement) for a standard normal population. (And, by standarization, the same is true for
*any* normal population.)

```
diff(pnorm(c(-1,1)));  diff(pnorm(c(-2,2)));  diff(pnorm(c(-3,3)))
[1] 0.6826895
[1] 0.9544997
[1] 0.9973002
```

**Empirical Rule--Approximate for Normal Samples:** However, the statement is not exactly true for *samples* from a normal population
because the sample mean $\bar X$ is only an estimate of $\mu,$ the sample standard deviation $S$ is only an estimate of $\sigma,$ and no random sample can
precisely imitate the population from which it was taken.

For example, the sample below of size $n = 100$ is taken from the population
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=50, \sigma = 10)$ (rounded to integers).

```
set.seed(829);  sort(round(rnorm(100, 50, 10)))
 [1] 26 29 31 34 34 34 35 35 35 36 37 37 38 38 39 40 40 40 40 40 41 41 41 42 42
[26] 43 43 43 44 44 44 45 45 45 45 45 45 46 47 47 47 47 48 49 49 49 49 50 50 50
[51] 50 50 51 51 51 52 52 53 53 53 53 54 54 54 54 54 55 55 55 55 56 56 56 56 56
[76] 57 57 58 58 59 59 59 60 60 61 61 61 62 63 64 65 65 65 66 66 67 67 68 76 78
```

The sample mean is $\bar X = 50.05$ and the sample SD is $S = 10.345.$

```
a = mean(x);  s = sd(x);  a;  s
[1] 50.05
[1] 10.34591
```

For this sample, we compute the proportion of observations falling within the intervals
$\bar X \pm S,\, \bar X \pm 2S,$ and $ \bar S \pm 3s.$ In this particular
example the results are 69%, 96% and 100%.

```
mean((x > a-s) & (x < a+s))
[1] 0.69
mean((x > a-2*s) & (x < a+2*s))
[1] 0.96
mean((x > a-3*s) & (x < a+3*s))
[1] 1
```

Here are a few more runs of the same experiment, with different normal samples.
For samples as large as $n = 100,$ results are fairly good, but it would be
a mistake to view 68%, 95%, and 99.7% as anything more than reasonable approximations.

```
x = sort(round(rnorm(100, 50, 10)));  a=mean(x);  s = sd(x);  a;  s
[1] 50.07
[1] 9.252087
mean((x > a-s) & (x < a+s))
[1] 0.68
mean((x > a-2*s) & (x < a+2*s))
[1] 0.94
mean((x > a-3*s) & (x < a+3*s))
[1] 1

x = sort(round(rnorm(100, 50, 10)));  a=mean(x);  s = sd(x);  a;  s
[1] 49.93
[1] 9.305429
mean((x > a-s) & (x < a+s))
[1] 0.67
mean((x > a-2*s) & (x < a+2*s))
[1] 0.96
mean((x > a-3*s) & (x < a+3*s))
[1] 1

x = sort(round(rnorm(100, 50, 10)));  a=mean(x);  s = sd(x);  a;  s
[1] 49.49
[1] 8.9324
mean((x > a-s) & (x < a+s))
[1] 0.7
mean((x > a-2*s) & (x < a+2*s))
[1] 0.93
mean((x > a-3*s) & (x < a+3*s))
[1] 1
```

The Empirical Rule doesn't work as well for smaller samples. In some textbook
examples with smaller $n,$ the excellent performance of the Empirical Rule
may depend on carefully contrived examples. The example below may be more typical:

```
x = sort(round(rnorm(25, 50, 19)));  a=mean(x);  s = sd(x);  x;  a;  s
 [1]  12  16  22  24  25  36  37  37  37  38  39  40  41
[14]  48  50  52  54  55  56  60  60  61  81  98 100
[1] 47.16
[1] 22.17671
```

You can verify that percentages within one, two, and three sample standard deviations of the sample mean for these data are 72%, 92%, and 100%, respectively. [After half a dozen runs, I got an example with
percentages 68%, 96% and 100%. With $n=25,$ exactly 95% is impossible.]

**Empirical Rule--Possibly Useful for Some Non-normal Data:** The Empirical Rule does not work quite as well for non-normal data,
but results for a sample from a (skewed) gamma distribution with shape
parameter 5 are not really bad:

```
x = sort(round(rgamma(100, 5, .1)));  a=mean(x);  s = sd(x);  a;  s
[1] 51.4
[1] 23.09926
```

[image]

```
mean((x > a-s) & (x < a+s))
[1] 0.71
mean((x > a-2*s) & (x < a+2*s))
[1] 0.95
mean((x > a-3*s) & (x < a+3*s))
[1] 0.99
```

*Notes:* (a) 'Chebyshev' is transliterated into various languages is
different ways: 'Tschbyschef', 'Tchebychef', 'Chebychev', and so on.
(b) The two-sigma version of the Empirical Rule seems to be more robust
for various non-normal samples than the one-sigma and three-sigma versions.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect that deep answer on my question, and I had to spend quite some time studying it (mind you, I do not have stats background), but in the end, it was worth it so thanks for that. I needed a formula, and it's fine for it to be very approximate - I have found it on my own, and your answer has helped me to correct many mistakes I've made when I was writing it down, so I'm marking this question as resolved.

Comment: I have computed a definite integral as stated here (actually approximation of it): https://goo.gl/d5XwRD It seems to work as an approximation to an Empirical Rule and is good enough for me

Comment: OK: Got image at `cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*44rogWkqXt2HCL8nv4Fcgg.png` and it looks as if you're on the right track.